# Get hard drive model name with bash

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to get the various model names of my hard drives using bash.

I can do it if there's just one, using hwinfo like this:

```
hwinfo --ide|grep Model|sed -ne '/Model/s/.*Model: "\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```

But this obviously fails when there's more than one. One regular hwinfo output when there are several hard drives is this:

```
[faidoc@Delorean ~]$ hwinfo --ide
11: IDE 200.0: 10600 Disk                                       
  [Created at block.245]
  Unique ID: 3OOL.XFCtBh10jZ2
  Parent ID: qnJ_.3_X41NtKT36
  SysFS ID: /class/block/sda
  SysFS BusID: 2:0:0:0
  SysFS Device Link: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0
  Hardware Class: disk
  Model: "VBOX HARDDISK"
  Vendor: "VBOX"
  Device: "HARDDISK"
  Revision: "1.0"
  Serial ID: "VBfa9b1456-03d78f51"
  Driver: "ahci", "sd"
  Driver Modules: "ahci"
  Device File: /dev/sda
  Device Files: /dev/sda, /dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VBfa9b1456-03d78f51
  Device Number: block 8:0-8:15
  BIOS id: 0x80
  Geometry (Logical): CHS 1305/255/63
  Size: 20971520 sectors a 512 bytes
  Capacity: 10 GB (10737418240 bytes)
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #10 (SATA controller)

12: IDE 300.0: 10600 Disk
  [Created at block.245]
  Unique ID: WZeP.0xN7VsONW+D
  Parent ID: qnJ_.3_X41NtKT36
  SysFS ID: /class/block/sdb
  SysFS BusID: 3:0:0:0
  SysFS Device Link: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0d.0/ata4/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0
  Hardware Class: disk
  Model: "VBOX HARDDISK"
  Vendor: "VBOX"
  Device: "HARDDISK"
  Revision: "1.0"
  Serial ID: "VB350f9911-48221ae2"
  Driver: "ahci", "sd"
  Driver Modules: "ahci"
  Device File: /dev/sdb
  Device Files: /dev/sdb, /dev/disk/by-id/ata-VBOX_HARDDISK_VB350f9911-48221ae2
  Device Number: block 8:16-8:31
  BIOS id: 0x81
  Geometry (Logical): CHS 2349/255/63
  Size: 37748736 sectors a 512 bytes
  Capacity: 18 GB (19327352832 bytes)
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #10 (SATA controller)
```

Every drive begans with for example "11:" or "12:" so if I could get one at a time that will be the solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the info with:

```
hdparm -i /dev/sda | grep -i model
```

or, if you want just the model name:

```
hdparm -i /dev/sda | perl -n -e 'print "$1\n" if (m/model=(.+?),/i);'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which one you want a very easy way would be `grep -A8 -E '^11:'`

```
hwinfo --ide|grep -A8 -E '^11:'|grep Model|sed -ne '/Model/s/.*Model: "\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```

The -A flag on `grep` grabs that many lines "After" the match as well as the line with the match.

There's also -B for "Before" and -C for "Context"

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick and dirty `awk` statement that may help:

```
hwinfo --ide | awk '{ if($2=="IDE"){ide=$3} if($1=="Model:"){print "IDE " ide $0} }'
```

basically searches for the pattern "IDE" in the second word of each line.
if it finds that, it stores the third word of the line in the variable named "ide".

then it searches the first word of each line for "Model:".
if found, it prints the IDE it stored earlier and the whole line containing the model name.

so you end up with the name and IDE location in your output:

```
IDE 200.0:  Model: "VBOX HARDDISK"
IDE 300.0:  Model: "VBOX HARDDISK"
```

and it should work no matter how many disks are attached.